# How to resize Javafx undecorated stage?

Tags: javafx, fxml

I am new to JavaFX technology, currently I am working on javafx application, in which there is undecorated stage,I am able to **move it on screen using below code** , but I am **not able to resize this window from bottom right corner**, can anyone suggest me the solution.

```
public void loadPanel(final Stage stage) {

        myPane.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                xOffset = event.getSceneX();
                yOffset = event.getSceneY();
            }
        });
        myPane.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                stage.setX(event.getScreenX() - xOffset);
                stage.setY(event.getScreenY() - yOffset);
            }
        });


        this.stage = stage;
        this.stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        this.stage.setScene(scene);
        this.stage.show();
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you want to resize your stage only on bottom right corner, you need at first an if statement to check, whether your mouse is there. In addition to this you need to distinguish in your dragFunction whether this is the case or not. If this is the case, you need the value your mouse moved and add this to the actuall size of your stage. The value -10 in the code (setOnMousePressed) is like a border so that you have a bigger area where you can click to resize the window. You can adjust this value like you want.
This code snippets may be helpful:

```
    private Boolean resizebottom = false;
    private double dx;
    private double dy;

    myPane.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            if (event.getX() > stage.getWidth() - 10
                    && event.getX() < stage.getWidth() + 10
                    && event.getY() > stage.getHeight() - 10
                    && event.getY() < stage.getHeight() + 10) {
                resizebottom = true;
                dx = stage.getWidth() - event.getX();
                dy = stage.getHeight() - event.getY();
            } else {
                resizebottom = false;
                xOffset = event.getSceneX();
                yOffset = event.getSceneY();
            }
        }
    });

    myPane.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            if (resizebottom == false) {
                stage.setX(event.getScreenX() - xOffset);
                stage.setY(event.getScreenY() - yOffset);
            } else {
                stage.setWidth(event.getX() + dx);
                stage.setHeight(event.getY() + dy);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make your stage public static and use this code and customize as per your code:

```
stage1.setWidth(Your double value);
stage1.setHeight(Your double value);
```