# Is it possible to enable resizing without the title bar in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

I removed the javaFx title bar using :

```
stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
```

Then I am trying to enable

```
stage.setResizable(true);
```

to resize my application but it seems I cant be able to resize the window?
Please help. Thanks!

I already tried using :

```
tage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
```

Comment: Setting the StageStyle to either TRANSPARENT or UNDECORATED will cause all the "decorations" to be removed, including the border around your window that allows for the application to be resized. However, you can implement this behavior yourself. As I entered this question I saw a post under 'Related' that could help you get started: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24106406/how-to-resize-javafx-undecorated-stage?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add a button that sets your stage's `setMaximized = true or false`.
And add `MinHeight and MinWidth`

Comment: The question is not about resizing between 2 sizes, but about resizing the window the way it's possible with decorated windows by dragging the border...